# how to fit full images perfectly in card view with out cutting

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-image

I have a recyclerview with grid images in card view ,Iam trying to get images from facebook which has different width and height and  displayed  in card view,I can't able to fit these full length images in cardview 
my code:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/iri_cv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_4sdp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_fb_inst_pics"

        android:layout_width="@dimen/_150sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_100sdp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/search_unselected_trait_one"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

here i had tried  ***fitxy, center crop and  fit center*** and all but no use ....

In picasso :

```
        Picasso.with(context).load(Uri.parse(item.getImage_url())).resize().into(holder.ivImage);
```

here i tried ***resize(), centerInside(), fit()*** and all but cant able to fit these full images in card view of width 300 and height 100,
and these images are getting flickering when i select the image in recyclerview 
can u please suggest me how to do that ...

Comment: `layout_width` and `layout_height` of ImageView should be `match_parent` instead of fix size.

Comment: Could you check my answer ?Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `centerCrop` method .

```
Picasso
    .with(context)
    .load(Uri.parse(item.getImage_url()))
     .resize(150, 100)
     .centerCrop()
     .into(holder.ivImage);
```

**Note**

You can use `placeholder` and `error` method in `Picasso` .

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.error)
    .into(imageView);
```